# Como evitar que o iframe seja redirecionado para o início

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma aplicação que usa o iframe para redirecionar as páginas sem modificar a url. (Entendo as consequências de fazer isto.)

O problema e que ao atualizar a página com `F5`  é redirecionado para a página de origem, no caso a página de login, como evitar que ela seja redirecionado para esta página?

Detalhe, parece um comportamento dependente de navegador, pois o redirecionamento aconteceu apenas no Chrome, no mozilla e ie seguem normais, ou como eu desejo.

**Segue exemplo para testes:**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Router</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe src="pages/home.html"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Chama pages/home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Home</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Que chama pages/about.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>About</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

No Chrome, se eu ir ate about.html e apertar `F5` ele volta para home.html, que é o arquivo padrão do iframe.

Comment: c vc tive a possibilidade de usar um php grava a seção com o arquivo da pagina atual dai quando atualizar vc printa essa seção

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizei algumas modificações mas a ideia foi essa @Laerte.

deixei a url default e toda vez que a pessoa muda de página é salvo nas sessões, caso a página não seja encontrada ele redireciona para a página de inicio.

```js
var router = $("#router");

url = "index.html";

if (!!sessionStorage.getItem("url")) {
  url = sessionStorage.getItem("url");
}

router.on('load', function(e) {
  var url = $(this).contents()[0].location.href;
  var iframe = router[0];
  var ifTitle = iframe.contentDocument.title;
  if (ifTitle.indexOf("404") >= 0) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("url");
  } else {
    document.title = ifTitle + " - Portal";
    sessionStorage.setItem("url", url);
  }
});


router.attr('src', url);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100% !important;
}

#router {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="router"></iframe>
```

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Essa API nova do HTML5 é muito boa. :)

Answer (score 1):

Baseado nessa estrutura eu sugiro utilizar `sessionStorage` para armazenar as URLs.

Você pode ter um JS que estará em todas as páginas que estão dentro do frame e que você quer guardar:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(i = 0; i < els.length; i++){

    els[i].addEventListener("click", function (el) {

        var index = el.target.href.lastIndexOf("pages");

        var url = index != -1 ? el.target.href.substr(index) : el.target.href;

        sessionStorage.setItem("url", url);
    });
}
```

Assim toda vez que o usuário mudar de página no frame você tem a URL.

No index.html basta fazer a verificação e setar a página atual do usuário:

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem("url") != null) {
    document.getElementById("principal").src = sessionStorage.getItem("url");
}
```